# Shouldn't this give me the current date/time in seconds?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I want to calculate an oscillating offset value based on the current time in seconds so that any object can call this method and would get an offset returned that is synchronized to any other object that calls the same method.

This is my setter for the locationOffset property:

```
- (float)locationOffset
{
    float currentTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    locationOffset = sinf(currentTime);
    CCLOG(@"--- current time = %1.9f, location offset = %1.1f", currentTime, locationOffset);

    return locationOffset;
}
```

I'm calling this a 60Hz and the output looks like this:

```
--- current time = 1316013568.000000000, location offset = -0.1
```

...and it stays this way.  Should everything after the decimal be zero?

I expect that I can adjust the frequency by scaling currentTime and the "wavelength" by scaling the offsett, but I just need to get my sinusoidal locationOffset to swing back and forth based on the time.

It seems like the location offset should cycle from -1 to 1 every 2pi seconds.

EDIT: Adding the method that works now as it should.

```
- (float)locationOffset
{
    double currentTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    locationOffset = sin(2.0f*currentTime) * 12.0f;
//    CCLOG(@"--- current time = %1.9f, location offset = %1.1f", currentTime, locationOffset);

    return locationOffset;
}
```

It cycles every pi seconds and has a magnitude of +/- 12.

Comment: How do you call that method ? It should work alright, even though you should use the correct type (`NSTimeInterval`), as you're losing precision (`NSTimeInterval` maps to `double`).

Comment: I have an object (subclass of CCSprite) that calls this.  If it is in the correct state (or heading there) it will call this and add the offset to it's position.  This (potential) call can happen 60 times per second in the CCLayer's -update method.

Comment: Are you showing us the whole function???

Comment: (By my calculation, that date represents some time in 1974.) [Oops -- must have slipped a digit -- it is a date in 2011.]

Comment: Just for grins try using timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate instead.  I wonder if timeIntervalSince1970 is constrained to be integer seconds.

Comment: Also keep in mind that a `float` only contains about 6 significant digits.  You probably should get the double value and subtract off some constant multiple of 2pi to get it within the range of `float` with some fractional precision, or else use a double form of `sin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, your problem is that a `float` value only has about 7 significant digits.  You don't even have enough precision to express the integer value 1316013568 correctly, so you're effectively feeding the same value into `sinf` again and again.  Stick with `double` values, and use a double-precision `sin` function, or scale the number to a value less than about 6 integer digits before converting to float.

Comment: Thanks Daniel,  I've updated the question to include the answer.